# How much sunlight do these rooted mint saplings need?

Tags: sunlight, mint

I have rooted mint in these two types of setups.

1. 10 inch plastic pot filled with potting soil that has a water rooted mint cutting placed for more than 7 days. It has been in indirect sunlight all the while. (Refer to Image below)
   [image]
2. Cut plastic bottle bottoms with mint cuttings that have rooted but the upper portions are curvy not straight and taut (Due to grocery store mints being that way.) Last time I took them out in this condition without cutting the upper curvy tops 4 out of 5 of them wilted and someone suggested cutting the tops off next time. These have established new sideways branches in some, others have not. (Refer all images except No.2). There's some algae in the roots of one of the 14 day in water cutting.
   [image]

[image]

[image]
My questions are-

1. Should I keep both the potted cutting in direct sunlight now? If so, should I start hardening off? It has no big leaves but only small ones on top.
2. Should the bottled cuttings be placed in pot? If so should I cut the tops? Or should I wait for roots to get real dense? How should the direct sunlight schedule be?
3. Should the bottled cuttings be placed in 3" pots first? To prevent roots drowning?

Answer (score 2):

In general mint does best in full sun and with roots in soil. The full sun gives larger leaves, more robust stems and greater concentration of oils which give the minty flavour. Soil provides the nutrient that allows the plants to grow larger and in good health. Transplant the cuttings rooted in water to soil as soon as may be, and while they are adapting to the new soil environment give part shade to ensure the transition goes smoothly.

Comment: Keep in shade for two days, then gradually harden off the plants in +1 sunlight. Only show sun when wilting is not there in the transplants. Are these steps okay? What do I do if the cuttings are wilting?